# Polymer 2 - Updatestyles within custom event

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-11, polymer-2.x

Trying to update a style within a custom event
This works on Chrome but not in IE11

I guess the scope on IE this is changed differently to chrome

Any help appreciated

```
_handleMaximiseTap(e) {
  this.updateStyles({
    '--table-grid-height': 'calc(100vh - 9.5rem)'
  })
}
```